# Question about primes in $\mathbb{Z}_{n} $

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, integers

For example, I kind of expect that in $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$  $\overline{2}$ is prime but I don't know how to prove it (considering the fact that I can test all the different products, but I want a more theorical proof), because I want to show that $\left(\overline{2}\right)$ is a prime ideal. Thanks in advance!

Comment: One thing you could do is show that the quotient by said ideal forms an integral domain, and so it must be a prime ideal (as $R/I$ is an integral domain $\iff I$ prime, and if $I$ is prime and generated by $i$, then $i$ is prime)

Comment: In $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$  $\left(p\right)$ is a prime ideal  $\Leftrightarrow$ $p$ is prime?